# Are modern ram architectures (DDR4 or SDRAM) Multi-port or Dual-port?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu, memory-hardware

So I recently learned about dual-port and multi-port RAM but I tried doing some research on modern RAM architectures and if they use it but I couldn't find anything on it.

Comment: (Waiting for reactions here, check out [Electrical Engineering@SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).) (I think there's a grey area between *computer architecture* as discussed here and *component architecture*.)

Comment: While my understanding is that main memory RAM is now usually single-ported, modern register files are typically (at least) triple-ported, and caches often *act* like multi-ported RAM (for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106951/load-stores-per-cycle-for-recent-cpu-architecture-generations and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193349/do-typical-multicore-processors-have-muliple-ports-from-l1-to-l2 ).

Answer (score 2):

DDR4 is single-port. DDR5 is also single-port, *but* it's dual-channel. It can handle two commands at the same time, like dual-port memory. But those commands are expected to arrive over the same physical channel.

This is part electrical engineering (signal integrity at high speeds), part CPU architecture (multi-core CPU's with caches, main memory is used for cache misses, fairly unpredictable command mix on the DDR bus)